# Debian lenny 5 install php-dev

Tags: php, debian

I'm trying to install apt-get install php5-dev
but when I run the command

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php5-dev: Depends: autoconf (>= 2.63) but 2.61-8 is to be installed
            Depends: libtool (>= 2.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

How can I solve this situation?

Comment: You know what's disturbing?  Googling the error and finding this question as the #3 result.  Damnit Google, stop that!

Comment: tried to apt-get install libtool ?

Comment: @albertopriore, what happens if you try to install `libtool`?  Also, this probably belongs over on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: I've installed libtool and autoconf but it still do not work.
What can I do now?

Comment: @alberto, has the error message changed?  If so, please edit your question and add the new error.

Comment: not it isn't changed.

Comment: This is the standard message produced by apt when mixing packages with different priority. Recent versions of apt handle this situation a bit more gracefully, I believe. It will be easy to produce an explanation if you include the following pieces of information in your question - output of `apt-cache policy php5-dev autoconf libtool`, and the contents of /etc/apt/preferences and /etc/apt/sources.list. If you have anything in /etc/apt/apt.conf or added anything to /etc/apt/apt.conf.d, /etc/apt/sources.list.d or /etc/apt/preferences.d, list those too.

Comment: I also encourage you to read the contents of `man apt_preferences` to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to install php5-dev from squeeze instead of lenny.  The lenny version of php5-dev doesn't depend on any particular version of libtool or autoconf the way that the squeeze version does.  If I were to guess how you got into this situation, I'd guess that you got into this because you now or at some time had "squeeze" in your sources.list and installed some stuff, or perhaps you are referencing "stable" instead of "lenny" or "squeeze" in your sources.list and now you might be running some mix of lenny in squeeze.`apt-cache policy php5-dev` should tell you where you are getting php5-dev from, which might help.

Comment: I had a similar issue when upgrading from lenny to squeeze.  Make sure all your apt sources reference the correct version.